# Cannot get data from database using AngularJS and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am trying to get data from MySQL using PHP and show them using AngularJS. But here I am getting the following message in browser's console and became unable to fetch the data.

```
response <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\phpdemo\js\edit.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\phpdemo\js\edit.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
false
```

Here is my code:

edit.php:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($data->user_id);
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('dbtuts', $con);
$qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$user_id;
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
$r = array();
if( $qry_res->num_rows>0){
while($row = $qry_res->fetch_assoc()){
$r[] = $row;
}
}
$res = json_encode($qry_res);
echo $res;
?>
```

update.js:

```
var app=angular.module("edit_data", []);
app.controller("updateController",function($scope,$http,$location){
    $scope.errors = [];
    $scope.msgs = [];
    var id=gup( "edt_id" );
    console.log("id is :",id);
    $http.get('js/edit.php',{"user_id":id}).success(function(response){
        console.log('response',response);
    });
    $scope.update_data=function(){
        $http.post('js/update.php',{"first_name":$scope.first_name,"last_name":$scope.last_name,"city":$scope.city}
        ).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            if(data.msg!=''){
            $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
            }else{
                $scope.errors.push(data.error);
            }
        }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
               // or server returns response with an error status.
              $scope.errors.push(status);
        });
    }
});
function gup( name ) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
```

Here I need inside the success function(`i.e-$http.get(..)`) the console message should display all requested DB values. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: perhaps $data is not a happy camper on line 3. dump it out

Comment: @Drew : I removed this but the output is not coming.

Comment: I suppose by "dump it out" @Drew means make a `var_dump` to see what's in the variable, like: `var_dump($data);`. Not **remove** it. See here [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: yes @xpy sorry bout that

Comment: follow this tutorial [Angular with php mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229382/how-to-display-data-from-mysql-using-angular-js-php/26229425#26229425)

Answer (score 0):

success and other convenience methods are removed from $http. You need to use the promise-like API on $http like below

```
        // this will fire a call to js/edit.php?user_id=value
        $http.get('js/edit.php',{"user_id":id})
             .then(function(response){
              // data property of response object will have actual response from server
              console.log('response'+response.data);
        });
```

Comment: @ Arkantos : I added your line but it is showing the console output as `responsefalse` .

Comment: Did you check the actual response for that Ajax call in the Dev Tools (F12)  Network tab ? what does it say ?

Comment: Then you need to have a look at your PHP script. We expect our PHP server to send some response for the GET request that we're making in AngularJS. I don't know PHP but check the answer from `xpy` and see if it helps in resolving your PHP issue.

Answer (score 0):

`php://input` holds `POST` data so the `$http.get('js/edit.php'...)` request should be an `$http.post('js/edit.php'...)` request instead in order to make this work.