# Not getting json response in angular js $http

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to fetch some data from database but when i am returning the json encoded output to angular controller, it is not getting response data. It is showing blank. This is my controller

```
'use strict';

app.controller('customerController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("data/getCustomers.php")
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //$scope.data = data;
    })
    .error(function() {
        $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
    });
}]);
```

console.log is not printing anything. it is only showing blank. Here is my code to fetch data

```
$results = $con->query("SELECT
                    c.id,
                    c.name as companyname,
                    c.address,
                    c.postcode,
                    c.city,
                    c.country,
                    c.contactnumber,
                    c.dateadded,
                    c.plan,
                    m.companyid,
                    m.name as naam,
                    m.email,
                    a.companyid,
                    a.livemode,
                    a.srmode,
                    a.paypal
                    FROM
                    company c
                    LEFT JOIN login m ON c.id = m.companyid
                    LEFT JOIN settings a ON c.id = a.companyid
                ");

$row_cnt = $results->num_rows;

$data = array();

if($row_cnt > 0){
    while($result = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $result;
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

How to get this json response and how to display using ng-repeat .

Comment: This is weird... have you tried visiting your PHP page with a web browser or sending a `curl` request to see the actual response ? Also maybe try adding `header('Content-type: application/json')` even though it should work even without it.

Comment: what shows up in the browser debugger? any errors? What does your html look like?

Comment: When i am using same php code in a php file and doing print_r, it is showing data. But when trying to print data in angular response, it is not getting anything .

Comment: No error in browser there

Comment: When i normally tried this code it is working absolutely fine and when i tried to use same code in my app it is not showing anything. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229382/how-to-display-data-from-mysql-using-angular-js-php