# how to display output of PHP MySQL query using Angular

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I have written MySQL query to get a number of records from the table.
I'm very new to angular js, I don't know how will I display output of it into the Angular js.
kindly check with below PHP and MySQL query.

```html
<?php

include("../include/connect.php");

$sql="SELECT clientDB_Status FROM ms_approach_clients where clientDB_Status='Lead-Successful'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);

  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: An introductory tutorial on Angular seems like the ideal place to start here.  Tutorials will cover how to make an AJAX request and handle the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it.

```
<?php

include("../include/connect.php");

$sql="SELECT clientDB_Status FROM ms_approach_clients where clientDB_Status='Lead-Successful'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  $data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
    print json_encode($data);


  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You can see example link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229382/how-to-display-data-from-mysql-using-angular-js-php
```